# Can't display cinder, nova and neutron infos in horizon dashboard

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-cinder

I started to work on openstack, and have installed it on ubuntu, and after all configuration I'm having a problem displaying cinder & nova & neutron services on horizon [error impossible to get information on nova  , cinder , neutron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MglV.png)

Comment: Is openstack successfully installed? Can you see any error while installing it?

Comment: i've checked the apache log :
[Tue May 17 11:04:13.993476 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 844:tid 3050294080] Call to
list supported extensions failed. This is likely due to a problem communicating
with the Nova endpoint. Host Aggregates panel will not be displayed.

Comment: this is the error while accessing the nova,cinder or neutron from horizon, i am talking about installation part itself.....you would have definitely run a python program to install the openstack, please check its log for any errors.

Comment: no error during installation

Comment: could someone help on my issue

Comment: Its really hard to pin-point the issue, but the thing i suspect is the http link which gets associated with each of the component is somewhere broken, surely there will be some error while running the openstack, which you need to check...search with the IP address

Comment: Check all the logs on your controller, specially the keystone logs, I've had numerous similar problems because of keystone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run? (before that export your admin credentials `source admin`)

> nova list

If all ok, and no error. checks configs `openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py`

Maybe no user

```
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_ROLE = "user"
```